# Close Child Window with Parent Window After reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now, I can close child popup on parent page close. But in child popup, I make a function to reload parent page. After reload parent page I cannot close child popup on parent page close. Because the popup information is missing. Anyone suggest a solution ?

I have try to store win.open to sessionStorage, but sessionStorage can only store String information.

Here my code:

winOpen.js

```
var win;
$(function() {
    $(".closeBtn").click(function() {
        win.close();
    });
});

function winOpenCenterParseReferer(add){
    var url = add; 
    win = window.open(
        "", ""
        , "width=1200, height=600, location=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no, status=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no");
    win.location.href = url;
};
```

parent.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="winOpen.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:window.close();" class="closeBtn">close</a>
    <a href="popup.html" onclick="winOpenCenterParseReferer(this.href); return false;">Open Popup</a>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.html

```
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.opener.location.reload();">Reload Parent</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not as simple as storing timer id in sessionstorage. `window.open()` gives you a full blown window object. You can store HTML but you can't store DOM coz they hold some state and methods like `close()` have native code ( not JS but low level browser code ).So I would suggest try some alternative like ajax refresh

Comment: @Novice I have change to use ajax refresh and It's slove my problem tks.